# Access values of fields using form controls in javascript?

Tags: javascript, controls, htmlcontrols

I have a form with some text fields(mostly date fields) disabled for a particular user,but has got some value in it.I am not sure whether it is a read-only field.
anyway the thing is I want to access the disabled field value to perform some other operation using javascript

Here's the stringified value of the control

```
{"idbase":"row-4-cell-3","lock":{"vary":0,"fixLock":1,"hidden":"","epmSourced":1},"desc":"Plan_date_ac","name":"date-4-3","lockValue":null,"type":"AC"},
```

I tried using:

```
 form[var.control).value
```

and:

```
 document.getElementById(controls[var].idbase).innerHTML
```

neither works for me, it keeps throwing 'undefined'.

Note: only javascript, no jquery please!

[image: tried my best]

Comment: what kind of element is that ? do you have an Id for the same ?

Comment: No exact ID,since it's categorized based on row and cell value,we gotta go with description

Comment: then what is this controls[var].idbase ? Are you using tables for displaying data ? or someother controls ?

Comment: are those value put in any element?

Comment: it takes the control to that cell? and tries to access the field there?

Comment: @AKZhang not very sure

Comment: You are given an object in the example and told that it is the stringified  data ,It seems your control is something which is capable of handling an object as value like some third party dropdown , grid or something

Comment: How the value being populated in the desired fields  ? If its dynamically populated then you can create a dynamic id or else give static ids to the controls and try to get values using that ids

Comment: then.. how did you get that value?
from javascript? inside html? or?

Comment: you are trying to get the element data using document.getElementById and it expects an id so without id how can u get that ?

Comment: @AKZhang  i am using idbase:row value and cell value to identify the date feild and get the value from there,so far no success and i am hopeful to find alternate ways here

Comment: "controls[var].idbase" doesn't work as an id? i think it does!

Comment: are you talking about html or?
can u show us the UI with the source code debug?

Comment: @AKZhang Yes,it does involve HTML

Comment: can u show us the source code where wrapping this {"idbase":"row-4-cell-3","lock":{"vary":0,"fixLock":1,"hidden":"","epmSourced":1},"desc":"Plan_date_ac","name":"date-4-3","lockValue":null,"type":"AC"}, by using "View Page Source"

Comment: @AKZhang updated with UI pic

Comment: where does {"idbase":"row-4-cell-3","lock":{"vary":0,"fixLock":1,"hidden":"","epmSourced":1},"desc":"Plan_date_ac","name":"date-4-3","lockValue":null,"type":"AC"}, in the UI image?

Comment: or did you mean you want to get the data inside "row-4-cell-3"?

Comment: @AKZhang i want to get the data inside Row-4-cell-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a class. To get class data with Javascript. Used below code

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
x.value // to get the x value
x.innerHTML // to get the content inside the element
```

Refer: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: it returns [object HTML collection ] instead of the data

Comment: in order to get data.. you need to use ".innerHTML" behind. Did you mean like that?

Comment: Works now,Thanks! but what happens when the field is in editable mode,how do i get the value then?

Comment: to get value use ".value"